# E is not a legal path since it is not a concrete type (Scala 3)

Tags: scala, scala-3, type-projection

I'm trying to migrate a library from Scala 2.13 to Scala 3, but the existing code does not compile.

Here is a snippet

```scala
trait Identity
trait Authenticator

trait Env {
  type I <: Identity
  type A <: Authenticator
}

trait IdentityService[T <: Identity]
trait AuthenticatorService[T <: Authenticator]

trait Environment[E <: Env] {
  def identityService[T <: Identity]: IdentityService[E#I]
  def authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[E#A]
}
```

The Scala 3 compiler fails with:

```
error] 14 |  def identityService[T <: Identity]: IdentityService[E#I]
[error]    |                                                      ^
[error]    |                                         E is not a legal path
[error]    |                                         since it is not a concrete type
[error] -- Error: 
[error] 15 |  def authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[E#A]
[error]    |                                                 ^
[error]    |                                         E is not a legal path
[error]    |                                         since it is not a concrete type
[error] two errors found
```

You can try directly at https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GuqSqC9yQS6uMiw9wyKdQg

Comment: While unfortunately I don't know how to help, I thought it was still a good idea to leave the documentation describing the dropped feature https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/type-projection.html

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/play-silhouette/pull/36

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [match types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html) (and [Aux-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131067/when-are-dependent-types-needed-in-shapeless) for technical reasons, namely refined types `Env { type I = i }` can't be type patterns)

```scala
trait Env:
  type I <: Identity
  type A <: Authenticator
object Env:
  type AuxI[_I <: Identity] = Env { type I = _I }
  type AuxA[_A <: Authenticator] = Env { type A = _A }

trait IdentityService[T <: Identity]
trait AuthenticatorService[T <: Authenticator]

// match types
type I[E <: Env] <: Identity = E match
  case Env.AuxI[i] => i // lower case is significant

type A[E <: Env] <: Authenticator = E match
  case Env.AuxA[a] => a

trait Environment[E <: Env]:
  def identityService[T <: Identity]: IdentityService[I[E]]
  def authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[A[E]]
```

[What does Dotty offer to replace type projections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043630/what-does-dotty-offer-to-replace-type-projections)

[In Scala 3, how to replace General Type Projection that has been dropped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227132/in-scala-3-how-to-replace-general-type-projection-that-has-been-droppe)

https://users.scala-lang.org/t/converting-code-using-simple-type-projections-to-dotty/6516

Alternatively you can use type classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using path-dependent types:

```
//> using scala 3

trait Identity
trait Authenticator

trait Env {
  type I <: Identity
  type A <: Authenticator
}

trait IdentityService[I <: Identity]
trait AuthenticatorService[A <: Authenticator]

trait Environment[E <: Env](using val env: E) {
  def identityService: IdentityService[env.I]
  def authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[env.A]
}
```